# What is the advantage of using a center tapped transformer in a full wave rectifier circuit?

Tags: rectifier

A half wave rectifier doesn't use it, still it shows output.

Comment: It would be easier to discuss this if your provided schematics as support. Here, we cannot be really confident we figure out the circuits you have in mind.

Comment: This question is more or less answered already on, strangely enough, Physics.SE. See: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55698/what-is-the-role-of-center-tapping-in-a-full-wave-rectifier

Comment: I shall be happy if you can explain the circuit you have.I just need to know its role in the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A half-wave rectifier arrangement indeed "shows output". However, the filtering requirements are more severe for a half-wave rectified waveform, since half as many sine "pulse"s are produced compared to a full-wave rectifier. This means the filter capacitor needs to be at least twice the capacitance, and likely more, to prevent the voltage from dropping too much before the next half-sine pulse charges it up again.

If the current requirements are very low, then the additional filtering capacitance may not be a serious impairment, but in any application with more than a small amount of power required, the expense of the additional filtering rapidly outweighs the savings in diodes compared with a full-wave bridge circuit.

Traditionally, when diodes were expensive, a center-tapped transformer would enable a full-wave rectifier circuit using only 2 diodes. A non-tapped transformer would require 4 diodes in a bridge rectifier topology. With diodes much cheaper than transformers now, there would be little economic incentive to using a center-tapped transformer topology.

Comment: Don't forget that diode losses and heat will be halved with centre-tapped arrangement. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211866/full-wave-rectifier-vs-full-wave-bridge-rectifier/211871#211871.

Comment: With low voltages or high currents, having drop on 1 diode instead of 2 is solid argument against a full-wave bridge. Eg for like 20 years most computer PSUs (switching mode) were symmetric, because it cut the most severe loses (diode) in half. At 40 amps, 0.7V is a huge thing. Since last decade, those loses were addressed via active rectification - and again designs more save on power transistors and their drivers rather than on transformer windings. IMHO symmetric transformer is actually the dominant design today whenever efficiency is a concern.

Answer (score 10):

Compare the following three configurations (from [this](http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/5c007.pdf) document):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using the half wave configuration will require a transformer 78% higher current rating (and thus more expensive) for the same output current as well as twice the output filter capacitance compared to the center-tapped full wave configuration.

An alternative (3rd configuration above) is the four-diode full-wave bridge, which uses the transformer even more efficiently (24% better than the center tapped and 2.2 times better than the half wave) but requires four diodes, and requires the same (smaller) filter capacitance as the center tapped configuration.

However, it has a potentially huge efficiency hit for low output voltages because the diode drop is doubled (and so the diode losses), so the center-tapped configuration is often preferred (for example, in switching supplies).